# Zend Framework 2 Flash Messenger returning no messages

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, flashmessenger

I'm having a rather odd problem with flash messenger in ZF2. I'm using it in quite a simple scenario, save a 'registration complete' message after registering and redirect to the login page and display the message however the messages are never returned by the flash messenger.

In controller register action:

```
$this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('Registration complete');
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('default', array('controller' => 'user', 'action' => 'login'));
```

In controller login action:

```
$flashMessenger = $this->flashMessenger();
$mes = $flashMessenger->hasMessages();
$cur = $flashMessenger->hasCurrentMessages();
```

Both $mes and $cur are false (I tried both just to be sure). Can anyone shed any light on this?

I'm using ZF 2.2.2 and PHP 5.3.14. Session save handler is using the dbtable adapter and I have tried disabling this as well as setting the flashmessenger session manager to the use the same dbtable save handler with no result.

Comment: In case you are using zfc user check if it overrides/clears your flash messages. Had a litle trouble back in the day with that, too.

Comment: No I'm not using that addon but thanks for the suggestion - I'll double check if there is anything else that uses flash messenger but I'm pretty sure there isn't

Comment: Having the same problem; followed official docs and various tutorials with no luck. Did you resolve this @JaiCee?

Comment: Actually - which view did you use it in? I think it needs to be in action views rather than layout views so that it gets the proper context.

Comment: Hey Jaicee exactly the same issue i am facing.
When i use flashMessenger on other pages like changeprofile it works like a charm but when try to show the flashmessenger on the login page after registration it do not work.

Comment: @cptnk, I am using zfc user too. How to solve that problem?

Comment: Same issue here, but it wound up being the "remember me" code in the example I used to get started.  It creates a new session manager, but the flash messenger plugin will use the session manager at the time of the first call.  
The fix: make sure all sessionmanager construct calls are done before you call flash messenger the first time.

Answer (score 7):

To use the `FlashMessenger` controller plugin, you need to add the following in your controller:

```
<?php 
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

  public function indexAction() {

    $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage('Your message');

    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin/default', array('controller'=>'index', 'action'=>'thankyou'));
  }

  public function thankyouAction() {

    return new ViewModel();
  }

}
```

Add the following to the `thankyou.phtml` view template:

```
<?php 

if ($this->flashMessenger()->hasMessages()) {

    echo '<div class="alert alert-info">';

    $messages = $this->flashMessenger()->getMessages();
    foreach($messages as $message) {
        echo $message;
    }

    echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

Comment: This is basically what I have (I'm checking in the controller rather than the view) but have tested in the view as well but the messages are never able to be restored from the redirected view.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your code is as it should be, there must be something tricky in the workflow.

In this case, you can debug the old way : try `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see if it is populated by your flashMessenger.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
echo $this->flashMessenger()->renderCurrent(...
```

instead of

```
echo $this->flashMessenger()->render(...
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem for (login flashmessage after registration) I solved it in the following way

Apply a check on your layout page like

```
<?php if($this->zfcUserIdentity()) {  ?> 
                        <div id="flashMessageDiv" class="hide">
                            <?php echo isset($flashMessages) && isset($flashMessages['0']) ? $flashMessages['0'] : ''; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
```

That means layout flashMessageDiv is accessible only to the logined user . now on your login view file (login.phtml)
apply the following code

```
   <?php $pathArray = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
            $pathArray = explode("/",$pathArray);
        ?>

       <?php if ($pathArray[4] === 'register') { ?>   
            <div id="flashMessageDiv" class="hide">
                <?php  echo "User details saved successfully"; ?>
            </div>
       <?php } ?>
```

In the above code i used HTTP_REFERER which will simply give us the referer url details check if  referer url is register then show falshmessage.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

The FlashMessenger is now an official view helper in ZF2 and can be easily integrated in every view / layout:
[FlashMessenger Helper — Zend Framework 2 2.3.1 documentation - Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.flash-messenger.html#sample-modification-for-twitter-bootstrap-3)

It works with TwitterBootstrap3 too and there is an alternative configuration for your module.config.php.